# Permanently ignore local changes to tracked files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder with a template project in my repo. After push, the folder was added to .gitignore. This works great regarding **new** files, but it still tracks **modified** ones.

I know about the option to ignore changes locally with

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

but I want both **new** and **modified** files to be ignored for all users of the repo.

How can i make git ignore the modified files, preferrably set in .gitignore?

Comment: use `git rm` to remove the tracked files from git.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring files in Git after they have been committed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542077/ignoring-files-in-git-after-they-have-been-committed)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **.gitignore** to ignore **new** files  and  **update-index --assume-unchanged** to ignore **versioned** files